# 360 panorama image with Ionic/Cordova

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I want to capture 360 view image from device camera. Is there any plugin or setting for camera available in Ionic/Cordova that can facilitate me starting device camera with appropriate settings/options of 360 panorama mode?

Comment: I want to do that in ionic2/4, any help???

Comment: I also want to capture panoramic view, any solution?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @karansharma I then tried a work around to capture multiple images and save them in panoramic way.

Comment: @MuhammadUmar how u do that .. can u please help to share some example code .. thanks